# Android- how to Display split two StreetView in one layout

Tags: java, android

I'm try to load split two StreetView in one layout file like as left side one streetView and right side another one StreetView. once run my app left side streetview will be loaded but right side will be black screen. kindly find the attached image and source code.

How to resolve this problem.kindly guide me..
advance thanks
[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:map="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/map_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/map_container2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/left_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment" />

        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/right_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            class="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

MyActivity.java

```
 public class MyActivity extends FragmentActivity
         {
 private StreetViewPanorama mStreetViewPanorama,mStreetViewPanoramaOne;

          @Override
            protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.main);
        SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragment =
                        (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment)
                                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.left_fragment);
                streetViewPanoramaFragment.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(
                        new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
                                mStreetViewPanorama = panorama;

                                    mStreetViewPanorama.setPosition("zlUWGaaVhOMAAAQW-bHrpg");

                            }
                        });
     SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment streetViewPanoramaFragmentOne =
                        (SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment)
                                getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.right_fragment);
                streetViewPanoramaFragmentOne.getStreetViewPanoramaAsync(
                        new OnStreetViewPanoramaReadyCallback() {
                            @Override
                            public void onStreetViewPanoramaReady(StreetViewPanorama panorama) {
                                mStreetViewPanoramaOne = panorama;

                                    mStreetViewPanoramaOne .setPosition("zlUWGaaVhOMAAAQW-bHrpg");

                            }
                        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Android doesn't support having two StreetViews in the one layout. Reference: [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/business/mobile/android/reference/com/google/android/m4b/maps/SupportStreetViewPanoramaFragment).